# Is it possible to launch a signed .ipa application on iOS Simulator without crashes

Tags: ios, automation, ios-simulator, appium

- **Purpose:**  Launch signed ios application Automation using Appium
- **Lauch:** Trying to launch the application via Appium inspector
- **Application detail:** ios Application, signed by a 3rd party developer. Only `.ipa` extions available
- **Issue:** App opens and crashes, continuously keeps crashing.
- **Device options** Different simulators - result is same and Real devices.

**Logs from Simulator**

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air profiled[1132]: (Error) MC: Failed to write /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles/Library/ConfigurationProfiles/ClientTruth.plist with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air installd[1101]: 0x700000117000 -[MIBundle _validateWithError:]: 30: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/Photo Booth.app
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154.launchd_sim[1091] (com.apple.iad.limitadtrackingd[1167]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/libexec/limitadtrackingd
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154.launchd_sim[1091] (com.apple.iad.limitadtrackingd[1167]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air dataaccessd[1165]: (Error) MC: MobileContainerManager gave us a path we weren't expecting; file a radar against them
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Expected: /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Actual: /Users/Salman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Overriding MCM with the one true path
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air dataaccessd[1165]: table drop: 101

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:50 Muhammads-MacBook-Air installd[1101]: 0x700000117000 __69-[MIFileManager urlsForItemsInDirectoryAtURL:ignoringSymlinks:error:]_block_invoke: Ignoring symlink at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/CFNetworkAgent
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:51 Muhammads-MacBook-Air dataaccessd[1165]: table drop: 101
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:51 Muhammads-MacBook-Air dataaccessd[1165]: Bogus event on event stream listener.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:51 Muhammads-MacBook-Air dataaccessd[1165]: 0x7f9f7a504f70|SubCal|Error|Error fetching subscribed holiday calendars. Giving up for now. Error Domain=CoreDAVErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
    UILabel:0x7fc65b5ab160' '.firstBaseline == SPUISearchTableHeaderView:0x7fc65b5a8580.top + 36>
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:54:54 Muhammads-MacBook-Air SpringBoard[1107]: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Try this:
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] (
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc65b5af850 
    info: Launching instruments

    info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 5s (9.3)
    info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 5s (9.3)" /var/folders/ks/ybjl6ngd2056zt6c30y6v4sm0000gn/T/116329-663-1x53997/Payload/Discovery.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/Salman/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
    info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
    info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Apr 29 11:55:05 Muhammads-MacBook-Air CoreSimulatorBridge[1115]: Requesting installation of file:///var/folders/ks/ybjl6ngd2056zt6c30y6v4sm0000gn/T/116329-663-1x53997/Payload/Discovery.app/ with options: {
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] CFBundleIdentifier = "com.ctv.dailyplanet";
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] PackageType = Developer;
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] SimulatorRootPath = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk";
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] SimulatorUserPath = "/Users/Salman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154/data";
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] }

    info: [debug] Cleaning app data files

    warn: Applications directory /Users/Salman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154/data/Containers/Data/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?
    warn: Applications directory /Users/Salman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154/data/Containers/Bundle/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?
    info: Couldn't find app directories to delete. Probably it's not installed
    info: [debug] Resetting Content and Settings for Simulator
    info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase E2D19473-66F0-4A32-9DD0-DCA4EF863154 and timeout: 2000

    error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

    info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
    info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
        at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
        at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
    info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
    info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 64280.563 ms - 182
```

**Logs from real device**

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 32271.057 ms - 182
```

**Objective:**

- To automate the application.
- To launch either on simulator or on real device and inspect the
     application elements.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Your ipa is a device application bundle, not suitable for the simulator.

Comment: Thank you, but why am I not able to launch the inspector on real device? I can upload the complete logs if required ?